# AVAudioRecorderがストレージの容量を使い切る恐れについて

Tags: ios

`AVAudioRecorder`で音声を録音できる機能を含むアプリを作っています。漠然とした質問で恐縮ですが、みなさまは`AVAudioRecorder`がiOSのストレージを使い切ることについてどのように対策していますか？

私の上司はユーザが録音状態でiOSデバイスを放置して忘れてしまい、ストレージを使い切り、ユーザーがiOSデバイスが壊れたと思うことを心配しています。私の上司はアプリのユーザーは必ずしもiOSの上級者とは限らないからそのような配慮も必要と言います。

確かにそのような心配は起こりうると思います。iOSの場合ストレージの容量が少なくなったらOSの側から警告が出るのは知っています。

一方で、例えばApple標準のボイスメモアプリやその他の録音機能を有するアプリで過剰に警告を与えるものは見たことがありません。`AVAudioRecorder`関連でGoogle検索をしてみましたがストレージを使い切る心配についてしているものはありませんでした。これはサンプルコードをできるだけ簡潔にする目的があるのかも知れません。

『AVFoundationプログラミングガイド』によると`AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`には最大録画時間や最大ファイルサイズなどムービーファイル出力のさまざまな側面を設定できるとありますが、`AVAudioRecorder`については定かではありません。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893945/i-want-to-stop-the-avaudiorecorder-when-duration-gets-5-mins

では別の方法を用いて録音を5分で自動停止する方法に言及があります。

その他、色々探してみましたが結論に至ることができませんでした。みなさまのご意見をうかがえれば幸いです。